# ASP.NET Dropdownlist causing issue

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlist on my web form and the second one is synchronised with the first one based upon what value has been chosen.

Everything works well between the 2 of them and am able to use the values from them to carry out my function.

However the first dropdownlist seems to have an effect on my repeater and paginations. Basically it keeps incrementing the pageddatesource and clears the repeater of any data ?

The `SelectedIndexChanged` is only meant to update the update.panel1 where the second dropdownlist is but then am not sure how it further increments the page numbers and removes data from repeater?

**Here is the front end with the dropdownlists.**

```
<section id="section-search">
<div class="fleft">
Start Date: 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="txt txt-sml"></asp:TextBox>
  <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calStartDate" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right" Animated="true" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" />
End Date: 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEndDate" CssClass="txt txt-sml"></asp:TextBox>
  <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="calEndDate" PopupPosition="Right" Animated="true" TargetControlID="txtEndDate"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<hr />
Product Class:
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpProductClass" runat="server" Width="230px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpProductClass_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
   <hr />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
  Product:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpProduct" runat="server" Width="230px"  />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="fright">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFilter" Text="Search" CssClass="submit" OnClick="btnFilter_Click"/>
</div>
</section>

<section id="section-title">
<h1>Order Search</h1><h2></h2>  
</section> 

<section class="info-strip tr">
<asp:Literal ID="litResults" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</section>

<section class="track-table">

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litMessage" Visible="false" Text="<div class='wysiwyg'><p>You currently have no orders...</p></div>"></asp:Literal>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phOrders">    
<%--<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>--%>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rprOrders" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rprOrders_ItemCommand" >
```

**Here is my Code behind**

```
protected void SetupControl()
{
  if (this.StopProcessing)
  {
    // Do not process
  }
  else
  {
    if (CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite)
    {      
      if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        PopulateProductClass();
        PopulateProduct();
        PopulateOrders();
      }
    }
  }
}

protected void drpProductClass_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CustomTableItemProvider ctip = new CustomTableItemProvider();

  UserInfo user = CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationUser();
  QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
  qdp.Add("@UserID", user.UserID);
  DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_GetEmpIDByUID", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

  int emplID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserEmployeeID"].ToString());

  if (drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
  {
    QueryDataParameters qdp2 = new QueryDataParameters();
    qdp2.Add("@WR_ClassID", Convert.ToInt32(drpProductClass.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    qdp2.Add("@UserEmployeeID", emplID);
    DataSet ds2 = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_OrdersGetProductByClassID", qdp2, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

    drpProduct.ClearSelection();
    drpProduct.DataSource = ds2.Tables[1];
    drpProduct.DataTextField = "ProductName";
    drpProduct.DataValueField = "SKUNumber";
    drpProduct.DataBind();

    drpProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select Product --", "0"));

    updatePanel1.Update();        
  }
  else
  {
    drpProduct.ClearSelection();
    PopulateProduct();        
  }
}

private void PopulateOrders()
{

  CustomerInfo ki = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationID());
  int nKustomerID = ki.CustomerID;
  DataTable dts = new DataTable();
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUID", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));

  QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
  qdp.Add("@CustomerID", nKustomerID);
  DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_OrderList", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
    drNew["OrderDate"] = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(dr["OrderDate"], DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
    drNew["OrderNumber"] = dr["OrderNumber"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = dr["OrderItemSKUName"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUID"] = dr["OrderItemSKUID"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = dr["OrderItemStatus"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = dr["OrderItemUnitCount"].ToString();
    dts.Rows.Add(drNew);
  }

  PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
  pds.DataSource = dts.DefaultView;
  //DataView view = dts.DefaultView;

  //allow paging, set page size, and current page
  pds.AllowPaging = true;
  pds.PageSize = PerPage;
  pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

  //show # of current page in label
  if (pds.PageCount > 1) litResults.Text += " - Showing page " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pds.PageCount.ToString();

  //disable prev/next buttons on the first/last pages
  btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
  btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;            

  rprOrders.Visible = true;      

  rprOrders.DataSource = pds;
  rprOrders.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and could never figure out the root cause of it, we chalked it up to a bug in WebForms.  But we were able to get around the problem by setting `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` for the control or page, we ended up setting our entire site that way cause we found problems that it happened to solve. Let me know if this works for you too.  Wish I could be of greater help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I set that on my repeater as `<asp:Repeater ID="rprOrders" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rprOrders_ItemCommand" ClientIDMode="AutoID" >` and it still doesn't seem to help? :(

Comment: @Kevin Darn, sorry.  It was a long shot in the dark but I'd thought I'd try.  You could try putting it on the page and see.  If I remember correctly we put the `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` on the DropDownList(s)